Dynamic locking/unlocking of a protected Excel sheet
I'm in the process of creating an Excell version of an OpenOffice worksheet. I need two range (A7:D10 and A12:D15) to unlock themselves as to allow manual input when cell K6 or K7 indicate the value "Blank". I was able to do this in openoffice with conditinal formating which did not translate to Excel. I tried using a Macro in Excell but get Error 1004 as soon as I lock the sheet. Is there anyway I can achieve this, either through script or formula? The sheet need to be protected due to my companys policy. Thanks.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("$K$7") = "Blank" Then
        Range("A12:D15").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("$K$7") = "" Then
        Range("A12:D15").Locked = True
    End If
End Sub

It works fine as long as the sheets stays unprotected. As soon as I protect is, I get Error 1004, unable to define the property Locked of Range class.

Me.Unprotect Password:=..., Me.Protect Password:=...

Note: Revised code is based on Excel; I am uncertain about their compatibility with OpenOffice.

Any cell modification triggers the Change event, so it is crucial to evaluate the Target argument at the outset.
In the context of the Change event, Me refers to the sheet containing the modified cell(s).

Microsoft documentation:

Application.Intersect method (Excel)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("K6:K7"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="123"
        Me.Range("A12:D15").Locked = Not (Me.Range("K7").Value = "blank" Or Me.Range("K6").Value = "blank")
        Me.Protect Password:="123"
    End If
End Sub



Thanks a lot, it hellped! The error message is gone but the cell stay's locked no matter what. Is it possible Excel 365 does not allow that function anymore?

I've tested code without issue on Excel 365. What's the content on cell K7 an K6? Is it word blank?

It's word blank. It's just as soon as I protect the work sheet, even K7 is on "Blank", the cell will not unlock in range A12:D15.

Me.Range("K7").Value = "blank" is case sensitive. If K7 is on "Blank", the condition is evaluated as False.
